# common ActionBar and Side Drawer component for all pages native script

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have angular2-nativescript application with several pages. structure is similar to groceries example. All pages has very similar action bar content so I don't want to add all action bar and SideDrawer event handlers for each page or add custom component to each page template

Is there any way to have single ActionBar and SideDrawer component for all application pages? Also it is important to have the ability to access this component from all pages and call its methods from page class (so I can tell this component that it should hide/show some content). I want to use some action bar animation in future so my ActionBar shouldn't be recreated each time page changes

Answer (score 2):

I created components that contain side drawer.

```
import { Component,  ViewChild, OnInit,ElementRef,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from "ng2-translate";
import {Router, NavigationExtras} from "@angular/router";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "application-settings";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
import application = require("application");
import { Config } from "../../shared/config";
import * as elementRegistryModule from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData } from "application";
import { isAndroid } from "platform";
import { UserService } from "../../shared/user/user.service";
import { SideDrawerLocation } from "nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer";



@Component({
    selector: 'sideDrawer',
    templateUrl: 'shared/sideDrawer/sideDrawer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['shared/sideDrawer/sideDrawer.component.css']


})

export class SideDrawerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input () title =""
    @Input () backStatus =true;
    theme: string="shared/sideDrawer/sideDrawer.component.ar.css";
    private drawer: SideDrawerType;
    private isEnglish=true;
      @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent)
    public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    constructor(private us: UserService,private translate: TranslateService,private router:Router, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,private _page: Page) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this.drawer.showOverNavigation=true;
        if (ApplicationSettings.getString("language")=="ar") {
        this.isEnglish=false;
              this.drawer.drawerLocation = SideDrawerLocation.Right;
                this.addArabicStyleUrl();
    }
        if (!isAndroid) {
                return;
              }
              application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {      
                  data.cancel = true; // prevents default back button behavior
                this.back() ;
              });
      }


    back() {
        this.routerExtensions.back();
    }
      public toggleShow(){
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
      }
```

add it in every page and customize it using input and output parameters

```
<sideDrawer [title]="'category' | translate"></sideDrawer>
```